# Azure Data Factory HTTP connector not returning XML output

Tags: xml, azure, api, azure-data-factory

For one of our clients we are trying to extract data from a somewhat old fashioned REST API which returns an XML response. We have already discovered that the REST API connector cannot be used for this purpose as it can only handle JSON reponses. We therefore switched to the HTTP connector instead which is giving back data, which we were then able to write to an Azure SQL DB sink. The strange thing is that the ADF output is always in JSON, despite the API response being XML.

At first we didn't think this was a problem but I just discovered that array handling is not being done correctly. If multiple records are returned everything is fine, but when only a single record is returned by the API the square brackets around the array are removed and ADF no longer recognizes it correctly in the mapping because it expects an array. As a result the single record is not written to the SQL database.

We have tried using the Content-Type: application/xml header to force an XML output, but that also didn't work. As the API really returns XML, it seems that ADF is converting this to JSON on its own accord and not doing it correctly.
Is there any way that we can handle an XML API in ADF using standard connectors? We don't have programmers on our team who can create custom connectors so that's not an option. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe a header of Content-Type:application/xml sets the request body to xml. Can you try adding a header with 'Accept: application/xml' instead? See this link https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/order-management-sw/9.4.0?topic=services-specifying-http-headers.

Comment: Unfortunately using Accept: application/xml also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no connector supports REST APIs with XML responses in Azure Datafactory.

I am afraid as the only way possible is to have a `Custom Activity` or `Azure Function Activity` to invoke the REST API.

You can build a Custom activity with your own data movement or transformation logic and use it in a pipeline to transfer data to/from a data store that the service doesn't support, or to transform/process data in a way that the service doesn't support.

The Original post by DataItch : ADF V2 pull from REST API that returns XML | [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/68c41a5d-4cd3-4f61-8cbf-c9d86909ce80/adf-v2-pull-from-rest-api-that-returns-xml)

Comment: Thanks for this information. I had my suspicions but good to have it confirmed. Time to start reading up on Logic Apps I guess...

Comment: Apologies, I thought I did that by upvoting it. I've now marked it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you so much, no worries - Happy Learning :)